# HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume. homestead up

Tags: windows, bash, git, php, hosts

When I used the command "homestead up" it stopped working at 45% so I closed it and restarted my computer. Now when I try to run the command homestead up, my computer says resuming download then I get this error message:

> HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.

How can I fix this error?

I am using windows.

Comment: Why you don't use wget's `--start-pos=OFFSET` or `--continue` to resume downloading? I don't know `homestead up` command so I couldn't help you with this command (please link to man page of homestead up which you used)

Comment: I am not sure why but this worked for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to vote up!!

Comment: you're new on superuser so you can't vote up, Sorry